# Django - type object 'HttpRequest' has no attribute 'method'

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm getting an attribute error

> *type object 'HttpRequest' has no attribute 'method'*

but HttpRequest has the attribute 'method' as per Django docs.

My views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpRequest, HttpResponse
import myapp.pyfile

def function(self):
    request = HttpRequest
    if request.method == 'GET':
       return HttpResponse(pyfile_function())
```

My urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from myapp.views import function, index

urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^myapp/$', index),
   url(r'^myapp/function_url/$', function)
]
```

My pyfile_function:

```
def pyfile_function():
    x = DAO.qryListAutpagsCreateFolder()
    field1 = x[0]
    field2 = str(x[1])
    field3 = x[2].strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

    i = 1

    while i <= len(x):
        return("""<tr class=''>
            <td class='' colspan='1'>
                <span class=''"""+field1+"""</span>
            </td>
            <td class='' colspan='1'>
                <span class=''>"""+field2+"""</span>
            </td>
            <td class='' colspan='1'>
                <span class=''>"""+field3+"""</span>
            </td>
            <td class='' colspan='1'>
                <label class='form-field'>
                    <div>
                        <label class='form-checkbox '>
                            <input name='checkbox' type='checkbox'>
                            <span></span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </label>
            </td>
        </tr>""")
        i = i + 1
```

Traceback:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/path/myapp/views.py" in function
  12.        return HttpResponse(function())

Exception Type: TypeError at /myapp/function_url/
Exception Value: function() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'
```

I'm using Django 1.8 and Python 3.5.

The pyfile_function is supposed to render a HTML page with a dynamic list.

Thanks!!

Comment: Hi Isoni, can you give us more background information about what your code is doing and what you're trying to do when you're getting this error? Welcome to Stackoverflow

Comment: @Francis Thank you! I'm trying to  execute a function referenced in my views.py. It renders a HTML page with a dynamic list.

Comment: You still have `def function(self):` instead of `def function(request):`. The traceback shows you that the error is occuring on the line `return HttpResponse(function())`. If `function` is the view, it doesn't make sense to wrap it in `HttpResponse` like that.  You haven't shown `pyfile_function` either. Your code doesn't match the error message. It's difficult to help when you don't show the actual code and error message. If you can't show the actual code, then create an example project that reproduces the error.

Comment: Note that Django 1.8 is end of life and does not receive security updates.

Comment: Done. Django security is not that important because the site is for intranet access only without sensitive information to people inside the company.

Answer (score 1):

It’s not clear what you’re trying to do here. If `function` is a view, it should take `request` as the first argument. If it’s not a a class method, then it shouldn’t take `self`:

```
def function(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return HttpResponse("hello")
    else:
        return HttpResponse("not get")
```

Comment: I got _function() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'_

Comment: If you are using `function` in your urls.py as a view then you shouldn't get that error. For us to be able to help you, please edit your question. Include the full traceback, your current code, and show how you are using `function` to get that error.

Answer (score 0):

parentheses are missing, replace this line

```
request = HttpRequest
```

with

```
request = HttpRequest()
```

Comment: I mean this is technically correct that (one of the) problems the OP is having is using the class not an instance, but you shouldn't do this in Django and it won't have all the nice stuff you want on `request` if you init it empty.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist agreed